# Searching for a track on iTunes

Tags: python, macos, scripting, itunes

I'd like to *search* for tracks on iTunes using a Python script on Mac OS/X.  I found a way to access the iTunes application through:

`iTunes = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.iTunes")`

but I haven't figured out (yet) the way to perform *searches*.  A little help appreciated.

*Disclaimer*: OS/X newbie here.

**Note:** I am not looking for ways to access the XML/plist database directly.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that SBApplication is from PyObjC. You may be able to look over iTunes's Applescript dictionary to see what commands are available and access it over that bridge using syntax here: http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/documentation/pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge/api-notes-ScriptingBridge.html
More here: http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/documentation/pyobjc-core/tutorial_embed/index.html

Comment: And search syntax here : http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/search-for-song-in-itunes-library-using-applescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/index.html) (note, you'll need ASDictionary for online help):

```
>>> import appscript
>>> iTunes = appscript.app("iTunes")
>>> lib = iTunes.playlists['Library']
>>> for trk in lib.tracks():
...     if re.search("test", trk.name()):
...         print trk.name()
```

This might give you the most control by iterating over each item, but there's a much faster way too, by using applescript hooks to do the searching:

```
>>> trks = lib.tracks[appscript.its.name.contains('test')]
>>> print trks.name()
```

Check out these appscript [usage examples](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/examples.html) as well.

Comment: no problem.  I didn't notice the objc answer mentioned a bit earlier, but I suspect this might provide a more covenient API to access scriptable applications.

The docs are a bit sparse, but once you wrap your brain around how appscript is structured, it's not too hard to look at an applescript example and translate how one would do it with appscript.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useless answer, but i'd advise you to use AppleScript instead of Python.
Take a look at this piece of code:

```
tell application "iTunes"
 repeat with bTrack in (every track of playlist 7 whose artist contains "Golden")
...
```

Perfect tutorials might be found here: http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=25631

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather stick with Python.

Comment: and python using SBApplication is using the same calls Applescript makes so it is just a different syntax

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of:

```
script = '''tell application "iTunes"
  repeat with bTrack in (every track of playlist 7 whose artist contains "Golden")
    print bTrack
  end repeat
end tell'''
tracks,_ = subprocess.Popen("osascript -e %s" % script, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
trackList = tracks.split('\n')
```

I never tested this, though....